# Current concerns regarding Raspberry Pi

Tags: power

After doing some research on Internet, I realized that maximum current draw for all pins combined in **Raspberry Pi 3** is *pathetic* **50 mA**.  (BTW, in case of **Arduino 101** "...maximum current draw is **1500 mA**.")  OK, I know that RPi is controller and you need some amplifier to run energy hungry devices.  One practical solution for non-motor devices is the use of opto isolators.  However opto isolators themselves require cca. 5 mA input current.  Say you want to use all 17 pins using opto isolators.  That means that you need at least 85 mA, not counting for current necessary for SPI and I2C communications.

Does this mean that RPi is just not fit for even for such semi-serious projects and you have to revert to Arduino?  Or is there any other solution to use all pins without big fuss?

Comment: *"current necessary for SPI and I2C communications:* -> Without having looked it up I doubt that is much of anything, those are purely communication lines.  How much resistance is in 6" of  24 gauge wire, etc?  The devices are usually powered by separate 3.3V or 5V connections; on the pi I believe the former will supply at least 100mA and the latter 5-10 times that (but do double check that if you actually need to use them that much).

Comment: Also WRT "semi-serious": If you mean you want to build a self-driving car then probably more and more powerful hardware is required.  It is exactly what it appears to be, no more no less.  *If it isn't appropriate to your needs, save your $35 toward something else*.  E.g., other people with other needs are going to say an Arduino is no good for anything semi-serious because it doesn't have a real microprocessor or any RAM.  You can of course connect the two but now you are looking at upwards of $50-60 USD!  That's a lot to pay for semi-seriousness! ;)

Comment: @goldilocks I am aware that there is enough power in 3.3V and 5V connectors.  But let's say, for argument sake, that you want to play with 12 different devices that require 200 mA combined.  There is more than enough current on 3.3V and 5V lines.  However even by using common optocouplers you still need at least 60 mA to control them.  Which makes things a bit absurd - why having 17 damn GPIO pins in the first place if you cannot use them?  In this regard I strongly prefer Arduino.  I even don't mind C++, but 2 kB of memory - are you serious??  I guess combination of both is the only solution.

Comment: You can combine it with whatever you want; I use an FPGA that the OEM says don't exceed 25 mA per pin or 100 mA per bank (there are 4), but of course it only has a processor and RAM to the extent that you want to implement them, plus an MC with ADC like the arduino.  More realistic are servo/LED driver boards and darlington arrays (which may work for bigger optocoupler contolled stuff, I dunno).

Comment: Why 17 (or 26) GPIOS?  Keep in mind of those 17, at least 9 or 11  have [user accessible special purposes](http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs) -- there's the I2C bus, the SPI bus (and I think a 2nd SPI bus, not sure how useful it is), UART, 1 or 2 pins with a PCM/PWM clock, etc.  *Is it really intended you use everything at once?* Probably not.

Comment: @goldilocks Number 17 has already I2C, SPI and UART pins substracted.  2nd SPI bus is for me total mystery (I know where it is but I understand its purpose even less than the purpose of 17 pins).

Comment: I guess what I'm driving at is if you want to drive 17 opto-couplers then yes the pi is probably not the appropriate choice, *unless* you also need a general purpose processor and peripherals, which is what the board *mostly* is -- this is pretty obvious just looking at it.  If you don't need those things, then you don't need anything like a pi.  If you do, then maybe it fits the bill, but there may easily be **more** stuff that's required.  It's not $150 worth of hardware; again, no more no less than what it appears to be.  In the end it may cost you more than just $35 to do what you want.

Comment: @goldilocks If you buy RPi and bunch of LEDs for your kid to learn electronics, you are also missing the point.  Yes, you can teach him to control current to reasonable amount of 10mA, but you must also instruct him to use only 5 of 17 pins for LEDs (or even less if he uses any other sensor).  To me it is a stupid limitation (or surplus of pins) and consequently a designing fail.  But this is only my personal opinion.

Comment: Sure, it would be nice to drive like a 4x4 cube of decent size leds or something.  But keep in mind this is part of what *learning* about electronics is, isn't it?  There is a bit of math involved.  Also, to be fair (I'm not a sales rep), the pi is billed more for learning **programming** -- which is not an unsubtle distinction.  How many LEDs do you have to attach before you get the point?  If you then want to go on to do the 4x4 cube, you'd have to dish out $15 for an add-on driver board.  Etc.

Comment: If instead (or as well...) you want to get into the complex world of sensors and so on, there's enough opportunity there *to keep your kid busy for years,* lol.  Of course, then you have to actually buy the sensors.   You can buy 8x8 LED arrays and attach multiples of them too, if they have little driver boards included (~$10).  Again: It is what it is. For many of us, no doubt part of the learning may be learning exactly what it is and isn't.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem in practice.  I don't remember seeing any report of a problem caused by the 50 mA limit.  I have connected 8 RGB LEDs (3 GPIO per LED) to the Pi and there was no problem.

Comment: @goldilocks One of the first tasks that came to my mind is to program **traffic lights** on crossroads, controlled by sensors.  That require bare minimum 6 leds and two movement sensors.  Dealing with add-on driver board to me seems like distraction from basic problem.

Comment: @joan I am a professor, I always play by the book. ;)  You see RPi is still on the mail and I already studied everything I could hold my eyes to.  If someone authoritative says 100 mA is OK, I'll be in heavens :)

Comment: Obviously it depends on the scale, but presuming: 1) You don't intend the system to have all 6 leds on at once, 2) The sensors are on the I2C or SPI  bus (power from 3.3v or 5v rail); this is *easily* possible.  I would't even worry much about ending up with all 6 lights on.  I've definitely driven 4 @ 15-20 mA each, joan says she's driven *eight RGB* ones (although she doesn't say they were all on full white at the same time).   If you're a professor and you break a $35 instrument I'm sure you can count that as *learning* too anyway, lol.  It's real life, on a very small scale.

Comment: Dear all, please be reminded that comments are not for prolonged discussions but for clarifications with regard to the question itself... you might want to join our nice [Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery)

Comment: @goldilocks When I write the program you bet at most four LEDs will be on.  I am not sure about kids.  And with ever more shrinking budget for education it is no longer about *learning* but *saving*...

Comment: @joan what is according to your experience a reasonable limit for total current draw on all pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was just resurrected. The discussion is interesting but the question is based on at least 2 fallacies.

1. The "maximum current draw for all pins combined in Raspberry Pi 3 is pathetic 50 mA".

If so what is the reference? The electrical capabilities of the SoC have not been released, although there is an unofficial *GPIO pads control Extracted from BCM2835 full data sheet Gert van Loo 2-August-2012* (now @ [GPIO Pads Control](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio-pads-control)) which shows the equivalent circuit programmable from 2-16mA.

The Pi 3.3V rail is widely assumed to provide 50mA, but AFAIK this is not officially documented for the Pi2 or the other recent Pi.
The original Pi has an on-board linear regulator which was limited, but the B+ and later have a switch mode regulator which supplies more. The regulator chip (which supplies both 3.3V and 1.8V is rated at 1A).

2. Arduino maximum current draw is NOT 1500 mA. Maximum current per pin is 40mA (recommended 20mA) and Absolute maximum for the entire package is 200mA.

Comment: If I got it right, one can safely dry 16mA from all 17 GPIOs, as total is far below presumed 1A limit?

Comment: @Pygmalion Unfortunately things do not work that way. As I said there is no documentation other than Gert's extract, but I expect there would be an overall chip limit, such as the 200mA for the Arduino. There are more than 17 GPIO on the Pi3, but I am sure you can draw more - I personally wouldn't go over 250mA.

Answer (score 3):

At first let's consider the typical use case of the Pi (and nod to the fact that its processor is more or less comming from the mobile world). So both the design of the Pi and how most of the users are probably going to use it justify the constraints the current Pi imposes on its GPIO pins.

If a higher current needs to be controlled there are always options to do so, e.g. line drivers or switching transistors, such as the darlington transistor array ULN2803. Those of course come at additional cost and required board footprint.

If optocouplers are desired in the design, it's worth looking into **low-current optocoupler** as a way to overcome this issue. The use of low-current opto-isolators, operating at say 0.5 mA to 1 mA, would put it well within safe margins even when using all GPIO pins of the Pi.

E.g.

- [Toshiba TLP182 and TLP183 - low input current transistor optocoupler series](http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/en/low-current-input-transistor-optocoupler-series/52115):

> The Toshiba TLP182 and TLP183 are low input current-type transistor output photocouplers utilizing the SO6 package. By employing Toshiba's original high-output LED, these products guarantee not only a high-current-transfer ratio at the conventional input current of 5 mA, but also at the same current-transfer ratio at the low LED current of 0.5 mA. Especially when utilizing LED current at 100 VAC and other high voltages, these products significantly contribute to a reduction in power consumption by reducing the LED current of the photocoupler. [...]

- [Vishay - Low Input Current Optocouplers](http://www.vishay.com/videos/optoelectronics/low-input-current-optocouplers), such as the SFH618A which should be able to be used at 1 mA given its high CTR (Current Transfer Ratio).
- [PC817](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/43371/SHARP/PC817.html) is another generic opto-isolator with acceptable CTR down to 1 mA forward current and might fit the bill

Comment: These TLPs sound tempting except for the fact that I cannot find them on any typical RPi or Arduino related shop?

Comment: @Pygmalion They are available on sites like Digikey (which do offer order quantities as low as one or two) at the order of less than $1 each.

Comment: The PC 817 optocoupler has been a fave of mine, in that it works well under 1ma, has good CTR, and is the most common thing out there: I'd say that half of all switching type "wall-warts" use them, as well as tons of other consumer stuff that uses AC power. Look for the 4 pin "DIP" style IC near where the AC cord enters the back panel. Just keep your eyes peeled on garbage day, and be willing to dive!

Comment: @VIC-20, thanks for the hint. You're right it's a everyday optocoupler worth listing.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of micro-controllers out there, each optimized for a different use-case. There isn't a single one that is well-suited to everything, so whatever your project is, pick the micro-controller that is best-suited to it. Some have more RAM, some have more CPU power, some have more GPIOs, some are physically smaller, some are less power hungry.